# Hashmap get() method returns null but when comparing with null prints false

Tags: java, hashmap

There is a hashmap

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

It has these values

```
entertain - have, 

some - one, 

very - extremely, actually, really, super, 

auto - car, 

lunch - meal, 

wagon - car, 

truck - car,
```

Problem statement

```
System.out.println("test " + hm.get("delicious")); //prints null


System.out.println("test " + hm.get("delicious") == null); //prints false
```

why is the second print statement printing false, should it not print true?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Dont **tell** us what you supposedly have in your map. Instead, write a piece of code that we can run that fills the mpa, and that does do these print statements.

Comment: I addition to @GhostCat's suggestion. I hope you can understand why by the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050855/1491414

Answer (score 2):

The expression passed to the `println` method is evaluated from left to right. First the `String` "test " is concatenated to `hm.get("delicious")`, and only then the output is compared to `null`.

Therefore:

```
System.out.println("test " + hm.get("delicious") == null);
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(("test " + hm.get("delicious")) == null);
```

`"test " +hm.get("delicious")` is definitely not `null` (it's actually equal to the `String` "test null"), so `false` is printed.

```
System.out.println("test " + (hm.get("delicious")==null));
```

will print "test true".

Answer (score 0):

Before we try to find a solution to this question, we should understand that what exactly is `null` in memory? Or What is the `null` value in Java?

First of all, `null` is not a valid object instance, so there is no memory allocated for it. It is simply a value that indicates that the object reference is not currently referring to an object.

Let's come to the actual question. the following code is internally used by java to compare.

```
public static boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
    return (str1 == null ? str2 == null : str1.equals(str2));
}
```

I hope, now you can understand why your program says `false`.